# okhttp3.internal.http2.ConnectionShutdownException Retrofit Android

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using retrofit to submit clinical report including audio message and picture, always onFailed Retrofit invoke with error **t.Message** give **null** and **t.toString** is **okhttp3.internal.http2.ConnectionShutdownException**

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

get retrofitClient Instance

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

import static com.portal.app.portalapp.utils.Constants.BASE_URL;

public class ApiClient {

    private static final int connectTimeOut = 2, readTimeOut = 3, writeTimeOut = 120;

    private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(connectTimeOut, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(readTimeOut, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(writeTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

retrofit ApiInterface, method to update clinical report

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("api/updateclinicalreport")
    Call<FileModel> updateClinicalReport(@Query("reportId") int reportId,
                                         @Query("presentingComplaint") String presentingComplaint,
                                         @Query("pastMedicalSurgicalHistory") String pastMedicalSurgicalHistory,
                                         @Query("currentMedication") String currentMedication,
                                         @Query("isCurrentMedication") boolean isCurrentMedication,
                                         @Query("allergies") String allergies,
                                         @Query("isAllergies") boolean isAllergies,
                                         @Query("obsTemperature") String obsTemperature,
                                         @Query("isObsTemperature") boolean isObsTemperature,
                                         @Query("obsBloodPressure") String obsBloodPressure,
                                         @Query("isObsBloodPressure") boolean isObsBloodPressure,
                                         @Query("obsPulse") String obsPulse,
                                         @Query("isObsPulse") boolean isObsPulse,
                                         @Query("obsRespirationRate") String obsRespirationRate,
                                         @Query("isObsRespirationRate") boolean isObsRespirationRate,
                                         @Query("clinicalNotes") String clinicalNotes,
                                         @Query("provisionalDiagnosis") String provisionalDiagnosis,
                                         @Query("differentialDiagnosis") String differentialDiagnosis,
                                         @Query("treatmentAdvised") String treatmentAdvised,
                                         @Query("isHospitalReferral") boolean isHospitalReferral,
                                         @Query("prescriptions") String prescriptions,
                                         @Query("medicalCertificate") String medicalCertificate,
                                         @Query("investigations") String investigations,
                                         @Query("obsSa02") String obsSa02,
                                         @Query("fileAction") String fileAction,
                                         @Query("hospitalReferralImageUrl") String hospitalReferralImageUrl,
                                         @Part MultipartBody.Part hospitalReferralImage,
                                         @Part MultipartBody.Part recordingFIle);
```

onClick method to update the clinical report

```
ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
            final Call<FileModel> fileModelCall = apiInterface.updateClinicalReport(currentReportId,
                    presentingComplaint,
                    pastMedicalSurgicalHistory,
                    currentMedication,
                    isCurrentMedication,
                    allergies,
                    isAllergies,
                    temperature,
                    isTemperature,
                    pressure,
                    isPressure,
                    pulse,
                    isPulse,
                    respirationRate,
                    isRespiration,
                    clinicalNotes,
                    provisionalDiagnosis,
                    differentialDiagnosis,
                    treatmentAdvised,
                    isHospitalReferral,
                    prescription,
                    medicalCertificateCurrentValue,
                    investigations,
                    obsSa02,
                    fileAction,
                    hospitalReferralImageUrl,
                    hospitalReferralImage,
                    audioMultipartBody);

            fileModelCall.enqueue(new Callback<FileModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<FileModel> call, Response<FileModel> response) {

                    customProgressBarDialog.hideTheProgressDialog();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.e("Image", response.message());
                        getUpdatedBooking();
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(context, "clinical report updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<FileModel> call, Throwable t) {

                    customProgressBarDialog.hideTheProgressDialog();

                    Toast.makeText(context, "LocalizeMessage " + t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "LocalizeMessage " + t.getStackTrace(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Log.e("Error", t.getStackTrace().toString());
                    Log.e("Error2", t.toString());
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you try to explicitly use an older version of okhttp3? We see similar problems for http2 connections if we use the latest 3.11.0 but not e.g. for 3.2.0

Comment: issue resolved when I use last two parameters (file, e.g. picture & audio) with separate api call and other one in separate.